# Why does filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) allow test@test?

Tags: php, email-validation

I was just setting up the validation for a form in which I decided to try using the filter_var function to check the validity of my email address. I can not find out what filter_var actually allows anywhere though (since the documentation is very simple), and I found out that it is allowing an email address like test@test. Doesn't there have to be a .com, .net etc... in the domain?

Comment: Technically, `test` could be a valid host name in a local network so I assume it's correct.

Comment: Can you please post your code ?

var_dump(filter_var('test@test.', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));

returns false for me !

Comment: test@test without the dot returns false too

Comment: You can see the implementation here: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/filter/logical_filters.c?revision=297353&view=markup#l499

Comment: @Youssef: it it still returns false without the trailing dot I'd be interested in your PHP version?

Comment: actually such a filtering don't make much sense. only e-mail verification does

Comment: @Wrikken, i'm on debian lenny PHP 5.2.6

Comment: @Youssef: I can confirm it works as you described on that combination. Artefacto has cleared up all confusion though :)

Comment: filter_var('test@test.de', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) is not valid. The behavior must have changed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The behavior has changed somewhere around April. See [bug #49576](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49576) and [revision 297350](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/filter/logical_filters.c?r1=297250&r2=297350).

That e-mail is indeed invalid, or at least that's what the PHP developers understood. The source carries this notice:

```
/*
 * The regex below is based on a regex by Michael Rushton.
 * However, it is not identical.  I changed it to only consider routeable
 * addresses as valid.  Michael's regex considers a@b a valid address
 * which conflicts with section 2.3.5 of RFC 5321 which states that:
 *
 *   Only resolvable, fully-qualified domain names (FQDNs) are permitted
 *   when domain names are used in SMTP.  In other words, names that can
 *   be resolved to MX RRs or address (i.e., A or AAAA) RRs (as discussed
 *   in Section 5) are permitted, as are CNAME RRs whose targets can be
 *   resolved, in turn, to MX or address RRs.  Local nicknames or
 *   unqualified names MUST NOT be used.
```

The [changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) mentions this bug fix for PHP 5.3.3 and PHP 5.2.14.

Comment: The ticket for this bug is marked fixed as of PHP5.3.3 and PHP5.2.14

Comment: Great catch Artefacto. So I assume the rules have changed? Why has this changed? I wish they would explain what they are checking in the filter_var documentation. So will this return true before 5.3.3 and false after 5.3.3? The system I am using this on is 5.2.12

Comment: @Metro It checks the e-mail for compliance with Internet standards. The fact `test@test` was allowed before was a bug.

Comment: @artefacto So what is the most full proof way to check for this in versions before 5.3.3 and 5.2.14?

Comment: Should I just use the newest regex at the revision above?

Comment: @Metropolis you can take the RegEx pattern from rev 297350 and make it into a custom validator function or use it directly with `FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP` then.

Comment: OK, clear, will keep that in mind (and I'll have to change some @localhost email-addresses asap...)

Answer (score 5):

It is a valid email address. It isn't going to work on the Internet (at least, not today), but it is fine for a local address.

I would assume that the developers are taking the sensible approach to checking email addresses and not building themselves a system that is guaranteed to go out of date as soon as a new TLD is introduced. We have enough email address syntax checkers that reject `foo@example.museum` as it is.

Comment: Do you think section 2.3.5 of RFC 5321 doesn't apply?

Answer (score 4):

test@test is syntactically valid.

From RFC 5321:

> In the case of a top-level domain used by itself in an email address, a single string is used without any dots.

Only after this does it say:

> Only resolvable, fully-qualified domain names (FQDNs) are permitted
>      when domain names are used in SMTP.  In other words, names that can
>      be resolved to MX RRs or address (i.e., A or AAAA) RRs (as discussed
>      in Section 5) are permitted, as are CNAME RRs whose targets can be
>      resolved, in turn, to MX or address RRs.  Local nicknames or
>      unqualified names MUST NOT be used.

This does not necessarily preclude TLD-only domain names. In fact, run the following code:

`checkdnsrr('ua', 'MX') // Returns true`

getmxrr('ua', $array) // Returns true

TLD-only domain names (can) have MX records and *are* in use: http://www.to/ is an example. And here's some valid TLD-only domain name email addresses:

vince@ai

paul@io

root@km

joost@tk

admin@tt

hostmaster@ua

Source of example email addresses: [Tony Finch – TLDs with MXs](http://fanf.livejournal.com/72486.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, `test` can be a local / internal network domain, so that would work. I like it that it  correctly validates `wrikken@localhost` when developing for instance.

A normal `nonexistentdomain.foo` would have the same problem. If you want to test whether something is delivarable to a host, use `getmxrr` (and it that fails fall back to  `gethostbyname()`).

Comment: So is it best to allow local addresses? Or should I use getmxrr along with it if I dont want to allow something like test@test?

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to check using checkdnsrr? Because if their server is down, or something else, then getmxrr will return false. Right?

Comment: You would allow local addresses (mostly in known ip-ranges) if you want / expect to handle those. You could indeed use checkdnsrr('hostname','ANY'), didn't occur to me (although checking for either MX or A record (which should be the fallback if no MX was defined) would be more reliable: a registered domain may have no A & MX records, making them undeliverable). checkdnsrr / gethostbyname / getmxrr all use the same mechanism afaik, so if a DNS server is down or slow, it would fail / be slow for all options.