# Regex problem Email test

Tags: php, regex, email

i have some problem with pattern bellow:

```
/([A-Z0-9]+[A-Z0-9\.\_\+\-]*){3,64}@(([A-Z0-9]+([-][A-Z0-9])*){2,}\.)+([A-Z0-9]+([-][A-Z0-9])*){2,}/i
```

It match email addresses and i have problem with this rule:

```
[A-Z0-9\.\_\+\-]*
```

If i remove the star it works but i want this characters to be 0 or more. I tested it on http://regexpal.com/ and it works but on preg_match_all (PHP) - didn't work

Thanks

Comment: *(recommended)* [Is there a PHP library for eMail Address validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161342/is-there-a-php-library-for-email-address-validation)

Comment: For reference, in a character class you don't have to do most of the escaping that you're doing. Instead of `[A-Z0-9\.\_\+\-]*` try `[-A-Z0-9._+]*`.

Comment: *(fun)* [Mail::RFC822::Address: regexp-based address validation](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are plenty of resources for this available.  A quick search for "email validation regex" yields tons of results...  Including [This One](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585)...

Secondly, the problem is not in the `*` character.  The problem is in the whole block.

```
([A-Z0-9]+[A-Z0-9\.\_\+\-]*){3,64}
```

Look at what that's doing.  It's basically saying match as many alpha-numerics as possible, then match as many alpha-numerics with other characters as possible, then repeat at least 3 and at most 64 times.  That could be a LOT of characters...

Instead, you could do:

```
([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9\.\_\+\-]{2,63})
```

Which will at most result in a match against a 64 character email.

Oh, and [this is the pain of parsing emails with regex](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

There are plenty of other resources for validating email addresses (Including [`filter_var`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)).  Do some searching and see how the popular frameworks do it...

Answer (score 5):

Why not use PHPs [filter_var()](http://au.php.net/filter_var)

```
filter_var('test@email.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

There is no *good* regex to validate email addresses. If you absolutely MUST use regex, then maybe have a look at [Validate an E-Mail Address with PHP, the Right Way.](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585) Although, this is by no means a perfect measure either.

Edit: After some digging, I came across [Mailparse](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php).

> Mailparse is an extension for parsing
>   and working with email messages. It
>   can deal with » RFC 822 and » RFC 2045
>   (MIME) compliant messages.
>
> Mailparse is stream based, which means
>   that it does not keep in-memory copies
>   of the files it processes - so it is
>   very resource efficient when dealing
>   with large messages.

Comment: [`filter_var` up to but not including PHP 5.3.2 and 5.2.14 suffers from at least one bug though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406473/why-does-filter-varemail-filter-validate-email-allow-testtest/3406651)

Comment: Ah. Thanks for sharing that Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :

```
/^[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9\.\_\+\-]{3,64}@([A-Z0-9][-A-Z0-9]*\.)+[A-Z0-9]{2,}$/i
```

But like @Russell Dias said, you shouldn't use regex for emails.

Comment: it is for extracting not for validating

Comment: Then you can add parenthesis to the regex, 3 pairs here.

Answer (score 0):

You have quantity modifier after whole group:

```
([A-Z0-9]+[A-Z0-9\.\_\+\-]*){3,64}
```

So this will require minimum of 3 alphabetical characters and something like this:

> a5________@gmail.com

will not work, but this:

> a____a___a___@gmail.com

will do the work. Better find a ready well tested regex.

Also, you don't have starting and ending delimiter, so something like this will pass:

```
&^$@#&$^@#&aaa5a55a55a@gmail.comADA;'DROP TABLE :)
```

Comment: the quantity modifier check the whole group which can be  aaa,555,a12,fg8,f7ysf87s,8dfs9df.... it's work for all emails the problem is in the star. If i remove it works, but with star it can't validate all emails

Comment: I've reedited samples, forgot of 0-9, no used _ to show what i mean

Answer (score 0):

While I agreed with Russel Dias, I believe your issue is with this entire block:

`([A-Z0-9]+[A-Z0-9\.\_\+\-]*){3,64}`

Basically you are saying, you want;

- Letters or numbers, 1 or more times
- Letters or numbers, 0 or more times
- Repeat the above between 3 and 64 times